# Java Script in a visual webpart of Sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am having three buttons to display the images in small,medium and large sizes and this works on a java script and the problem is when i click the say i clicked small button the image is becoming small but the page is being refreshed so that the image is coming back to the normal state..I need to avoid the page refresh on a button clcik...

```
function changeimg(imgsize) {
    // improve later:  grey-out/disable currently irrelevant button
    var imgwidth, imgheight, imgid;

    switch (imgsize) {
        case small: imgwidth = smaWidth; imgheight = smaHeight; imgid = '1'; break;
        case medium: imgwidth = medWidth; imgheight = medHeight; imgid = '2'; break;
        case large: imgwidth = larWidth; imgheight = larHeight; imgid = '3'; break;
        default: alert('Javascript error 1; please shoot the author');
    }

    for (var n = 0; n < imgArr.length; n++) {
        imgElement = 'img' + imgArr[n][iname];
        document.images[imgElement].width = imgArr[n][imgwidth];
        document.images[imgElement].height = imgArr[n][imgheight];
        document.images[imgElement].src = 'img/' + imgArr[n][iname] + imgid + '.jpg';
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post the html-code for the buttons as well to enable us to give you as good an answer as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using an asp button, you will need to turn off submit behavior.

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" onClientClick="your-JS-code; return false;" />
```